# axios, cant pass data from react component to PHP file

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I have a react component that calls an Axios function. that function is a general API function that I use many times in my app and it works fine.
I am trying to send data to a PHP file.
For some reason I can't get data in the PHP file, I can see that there is a call and it arrives to the PHP file (I use xdebug for that).

this is the code I have:

the axious function:

```
const apiPath =   apiPath = "http://localhost/bibli/api";

export const apiClient = async(url, method, data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({ method, url: `${apiPath}${url}`, data })
            .then(function(response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

This is the function in the React component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const userid = this.state.userid;
    const page = this.state.page;
  
      // this.props.GetUserData(userid);
    this.getUserDataAPI( userid, page);

    }
    
    async getUserDataAPI (userid, page){
      let userDataKey = { userid, page }
      console.log( ' userDataKey value is on userdata.js ', userDataKey);
      let response = await apiClient('/users/User.php', 'get', userDataKey)
    
    }
```

in the `console.log` I do see the data that is sent and it isn't empty.
I tried to get the data in the php file using `$_GET['userid']` and using

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the GET method via Axios API, but your code does not send any params. As per [Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config), you have to use params property to send URL parameters with GET request. Doing so your code would become

```
const apiPath = "http://localhost/bibli/api";

export const apiClient = async(url, method, data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({ method, url: `${apiPath}${url}`, params: data })
            .then(function(response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

But URL paramters must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object.

Comment: When I added the `params` property I managed to read the data in the php file,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try by sending an `formData`

```
let userDataKey = new FormData();
userDataKey.append("userid", userid);
userDataKey.append("page", page);
```

I would use `POST` method for this case.

You should be able to read it with `$_POST['userid']`